# Indent text child nodes with javax.xml.transform.Transformer

Tags: java, xml, transformation

I'm transforming a DOM document to XML in java using javax.xml APIs. The result is

```
<tag>
    <tag2>text</tag2>
</tag>
```

but I need it to be

```
<tag>
    <tag2>
        text
    </tag2>
</tag>
```

Are there any options to do that with text child nodes?
I didn't find any

Comment: Why do you need the new lines? Seems a little unusual for a structured data format like XML.

Comment: I need the newline because the custom (and quite ugly) Fortran library we're using to read XML does not like data written as <tag2>text</tag2> , sometimes it reads correctly and sometime it doesn't :(

Comment: The Fortran library's XML parser is broken... It would be much better to have the Fortran library fixed. What good is a library that claims to read XML if it only understands its own idiolect? The point of a standard data interchange format is that tools that generate XML (the same standard) will be able to work with  it. If the Fortran library doesn't understand XML, you might as well feed it CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to write your own marshaller to do this, as assuming you want this formatting to apply to all levels of XML you want to take the String `text` and transform it into

```
[line feed character]
[n + i space characters]text[line feed character]
[n space characters]
```

where n depends on the depth of the current element from the root element.

Explicitly, if you compare the values of xpath /tag/tag2 on both these documents they are not the same.

Comment: The indent in the second line is too small, should be [n+i space characters]

Comment: This is what I'm coding right now, but I was in hope of something like transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.PUT_STRING_CHILDREN_ON_NEW_LINE, "yes");

Comment: The main point I'm trying to get accross is that the two documents are not equal, and if you actually want text with the new line character in you are going to get one hell of a mess...  You should give whoever wrote your fortran library a slap :)

Comment: The documents are different *but* the data itself is equal when you actually read the text children and trim it. I'm almost done with writing my own code to do that :(